# How to find nearest user in google map using map API In Django?

Tags: python, django, google-maps, location

I have a list of delivery agents(bikers) for a restaurant in the MYSQL database with longitude and latitude(updating in every 10 seconds). I want if the restaurant gets a new order, restaurant nearest agent will get the updating message.

I am stuck over how to do in Django. I know geoDjango is useful but it will give liner distance between two points.

Can someone help me to get the nearest user on the map?

Answer (score 1):

You can use django geopy [here](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
geo_distance = great_circle(biker_latlog, hotel_latlog).miles
```

which will give the distance between hotel and biker guy

and further you can implement your logic

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me if there are more then five bikers how I can get nearest bikers among them?